# What i need to fill in Data safety form?

Tags: android

We found an issue in the following area(s):

SPLIT_BUNDLE 4: Data sent off device undeclared in Data safety form: Device Or Other IDs Data Type - Device Or Other IDs (some common examples may include Advertising ID, Android ID, IMEI, BSSID)

Answer (score 2):

In your "data collected" part of the Data safety form, there's some information you forgot to add. By the looks of that email, your app is collecting and transmitting some information about the device, soo think IMEI Number, Advertising ID.

One thing you may have overlooked is the Firebase Cloud Messaging Device Token.

Add that to your data safety form and you're good to go.

In the data types. scroll to the very bottom and select "device and other IDs" and then proceed like you usually do.